# Jenkins Artifactory Plugin (gradle) doesn't read version from gradle.properties

Tags: jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, artifactory

Currently I try to configure Jenkins, so I can do my release builds automatically. It should change the version number from SNAPSHOT to a release version, and do all the SVN commit stuff. After this is done, it should switch it back to a new SNAPSHOT version and commit it, too. Before I switched from maven to gradle, the same plugin worked correctly.

I already created a gradle build, that works correctly. It is reading the version from the property "version" in the gradle.properties file. This version is the one that is used in the gradle build. It's also possible to run "artifactoryPublish" to publish the JAR to my artifactory.

**The problem:**

When I open the dialog "Artifactory Pro Release Staging" (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIGdp.jpg) it is not filling the fields "Release version", "Next development version", and none of the other fields. If I fill the fields by hand, everything is working correctly. As well the version in gradle.properties is changed and checked in correctly.

How could I solve this problem?

**Used Versions:**

- Jenkins Version 2.7.1
- JFrog Artifactory 4.7.4 rev 40169 (free version)
- Jenkins Artifactory Plugin 2.6.0 (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management)
- Gradle 2.14.1

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered opening a bug on the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin?  https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, when you access the "Artifactory Release Staging" page, the "Release version" and "Next development version" fields are empty. This might be because you did not define the property names for your version and next development version in your Jenkins job configuration.
Here's how you do it:
1. Open your gradle.properties file and find the name of your version property. For example, if your gradle.properties contains:
version=1.2-SNAPSHOT
then the name is "version".
2. Open your Jenkins job configuration, and put "version" in the "Release property" and "Next development properly" text fields. You should find them under the "Release Staging" configuration.

Now, the Artifactory Release Staging page should know where to take your versions from. This configuration is not required when using Artifactory Release Staging for Maven, because in Maven the version can be found at one place only - in the pom file.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did it like this. Here you can see my settings http://imgur.com/a/Muwpn . I Think that this should be correct, because the new version (setted by hand in the "Artifactory Pro Release Staging"-dialog gets written correctly into the gradle.properties in version=MY_BY_HAND_SET_VERSION. :-/ The once problem is, that the dialog did not prefill the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it seems your gradle.properties could not be committed with the rest of your files with SVN. Can you check this?

If it is committed and is effectively present with all the other source files when Jenkins executes the build job, it may be worth ensuring that the Jenkins build job is looking for the gradle.properties file at the right place. The Gradle plugin's default behaviour is to search for the gradle.properties file at the root of each project. If that's not where your gradle.properties file is, you may want to set the path manually. To do so, add the following under 'switches', in your Jenkins job:

```
-Dgradle.user.home=$HOME/.gradle
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: When I fill the "Artifactory Pro Release Staging"-dialog by hand it works and it is doing everything that is explained in the documentation (-Change the gradle.properties with release values (before the build starts), Trigger the Gradle build step (with optionally different tasks and options), Commit/push changes to the tag (Subversion) or the release branch (Git), Change the gradle.properties with next integration values
- Commit/push changes to the trunk). After I did this, I checked the gradle.properties and it contains the new version (I setted in the form by hand).

Comment: Did you try setting the plugin's location manually in your Jenkins job?

Comment: Yes, I added that switch (http://imgur.com/a/ZUUWp), but this doesn't change the behaviour.

Comment: I can confirm that the artifactory jenkins plugin (2.8.2) is expecting gradle.properties to be in your jenkins workspace root for these fields to be populated. There seem to be no configuration to tell it to look elsewhere and it does not extract it from jenkins gradle plugin. Find a way to have it in your workspace root.

Answer (score 0):

possibly this happens due to the below reason, while reading the properties

1. File permission - check the file group and owner in the work-space where your gradle.properties is located
   2.(Not sure on details, it helped me in resolving) After updating the correct file owner group, removed the version property from jenkins artifactory release management section  and triggered the build and once it is successful and included the version in  jenkins artifactory release management section and triggered the build and it solved the problem.